# Warning: Gem::Dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the default ruby Installation on my macbook (using 10.6). When I start my rails 2.3.5 intern rails server I get this Warning.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
```

How can I disable or fix it?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upgrade Rails to the newest stable version of 2.3.x (2.3.9, I think). This is an internal call from the rails framework based on how they were calling the method. You probably have 1.3.7 rubygems installed which is what is complaining, and its much easier to upgrade rails than downgrade rubygems.

you could also use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to create a gemset that has an earlier version of rubygems installed (I'd guess 1.3.5 or 1.3.6 should work) and rails 2.3.5. But if you can upgrade, I would.